# Open Redirect vulnerability fix in Javascript

Tags: javascript, security, redirect, xss, window.location

I'm getting Client DOM Open Redirect security issue on scan for the following piece of code. The issue shouws up at the 1st line where I'm initializing the 'currentPage' variable.
How do I fix this? 
Could I use whitelisting of URLs?
How do I create a regex to create a whitelist of URLs in such a case?

var currentPage = window.location.href;

```
var myPath = currentPage.substring(currentPage.indexOf("/myapp"), currentPage.indexOf(".html"));
var myHost = currentPage.substring(0, currentPage.indexOf("/myapp"));
query = encodeURIComponent(query);

if(myPath!==null){
    query = query + "mysite:" + myHost + myPath;
}
```